# What is the best way to store list of links to cloud files in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently working on a project which involves a django model which should have a field containing links to images on AWS S3.

The field should be a list of strings but django has no default field for this.

I have searched online and a way to solve this is by creating another model called imagesModel and link them by ForeignKey. But in my case I really only need a list of strings, so I believe there should be an easier way to accomplish this?

Some other people suggest creating a custom field to hold the list of strings and some suggest using JSON field to hold the list of strings.

I think it should be rather common to store links to images on cloud in django models and there should be a conventional way to do this.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is are you going to handle the uploads of those images?

If yes, then you'll have to create [custom storage system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-file-storage/) (or use 3rd party one, there're serveral for S3) and then use a separate model for images with [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield), which will store the paths, and link it via many-to-many to your main model.

If no, which means you'll just need to return links to the images, then one solution is to use a separate model for images with [URLFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#urlfield), which will store the images' URLs, and link it via many-to-many to your main model. Or if the images don't repeat between records in main model, and there're a few of them correspond to each record, then denormalization would work granting performance boost - use a field on main model to store a list of strings. `JSONField` sounds nice as JSON perfect to store a list of strings, but it's specific for [PostgreSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). 
But if the list of strings is in fact the list of URLs, that won't contain spaces, then the easy way is to just `text_filed_value=" ".join(list_of_strings)` them and store in common [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#textfield) on the main model and then `list_of_strings=text_field_value.split(" ")` to get them back as list of strings.

Comment: You're welcome! One note, [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) is actually Django's built-in in contrib package, but it's specific to PostgreSQL database. I'll edit the answer to state this.

Answer (score 1):

So you have one model in which you want to save a list of strings (links). The easiest way to do that is by creating a separate model with a textfield and a one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Models.FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField). Use the upload_to attribute to point to the remote storage.

Comment: I recommend the django "storages" app which uses this method